# BigQuery Standard SQL Windowing function based on previous rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Some Background for the question - Running a Standard SQL query on BigQuery for solving a problem.

The sample data I am using is as below :

| field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 9 | 9 |

What I am trying to achieve is that if field1 and field2 are matching, I want to start a counter from 0 i.e 0, 1,2,3 and if values for field1 and field2 are not matching for consecutive next row, then counter should be reset from 0 i.e 0,1,2,3

The expected output for below sample data is :

| field1 | field2 | counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 6 | 2 |
| 9 | 9 | 3 |

The sequence of field1 and field2 cant be changed as I am ordering them before any logic.

The query I have tried is  :

```
tmp as (
select *, CASE WHEN field1=field2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as counter from tmp
  )
select field1, field2, if(lag=1 and counter=1,counter+1,counter) as counter FROM (
SELECT field1, field2, counter, LAG(counter) OVER (ORDER BY field1) as lag
FROM tmp
ORDER BY field1, field2
)
```

But I am unable to build the logic to increment the counter beyong 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't build a counter like that in SQL. Each result row must be calculatable without referring to another result row. *(Window functions can only refer to different rows in the inputs, not the results.)*

So, you need to create a column you can partition the data by (the start of each partition enabling the counter to 'reset from 0').

```
WITH
  bounded AS
(
  SELECT
    tmp.*,
    SUM(IF(field1=field2, 0, 1)) OVER (ORDER BY field1) AS grp
  FROM
    tmp
)
SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  SUM(IF(field1=field2, 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY field1) AS counter
FROM
  bounded
```

Comment: thanks a lot brother, this is the exact query I was looking for.